# Create a function with array of object with different generic types and output input types

Tags: swift, generics

I've a an object with generic called `MyObject<T>`.
Now suppose an array of `MyObject` with different generic types like:

- `MyObject<A>`
- `MyObject<B>`
- `MyObject<C>`

Is possibile to create a function which takes a collection of these objects and has as output their types (`[A,B,C]`)?

Something like: `func myFunc(_ input: [MyObject<A,B,C>]) -> [A,B,C]`

Comment: No. An array has only one generic type, you could use other datastructures like tuples for this purpose, but not one basic array. Just think about the type the array would have to have as a method parameter - `[MyObject<A,B,C>]` is obviously not possible if `MyObject` has only one generic parameter. There simply is no way to express the array type using `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: An array is not necessary, I could also use variadic args if some sort of pattern is permitted. Basically I should return objects of the same type I've passed as input in the same order.

Comment: but you want to be able to call the same method with 2 or 3 or 4 or some dynamic amount of parameters?

Comment: Exactly I can do it with a fixed number of paeans but I would to know if is possible to replicate the same behavior with a variadic number.